# how to increase checkbox border without using images in android

Tags: android, checkbox, size, width, border

Found lot of questions/answers about how to change 1. checkbox color, checkbox borer color etc but not about increasing check box border(border of square).

My checkbox xml code below

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/mChkAgree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/black"
        android:scaleX="1.70"
        android:scaleY="1.70"
        android:text="@string/agree_text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Now the checkbox border is barely visible

[image]

So how to increase the border(width) of square shaped check box?

Also I don't want to use images for checkbox, so is it possible without using custom images?

Answer (score 0):

According with this post: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/

The best way to increase the border of square is using a checkbox with custom android:drawable tag.

Example of custom drawable (put to /res/xml folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="4px"/>
<size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

And...

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/mChkAgree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/black"
    android:scaleX="1.70"
    android:scaleY="1.70"
    android:text="@string/agree_text"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
    android:drawable="@xml/custom_checkbox />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but your solution and also the solution in that post don't work. Your solution has no effect while solution in that link give square filled with black color